# Does my data fit an exponential distribution? And what does it mean?

Tags: distributions, fitting, exponential-distribution

I have gathered the following data sets, 24 readings for 7 days and it is as follows:
mydata<-c(0.1083,0,0,0,0,0.0083,0.05,0.1667,0.6583,0.7917,1.0333,1.4333,0.9833,1.0417,0.9917,0.8833,1.15,0.77,1.2083,1.05,1.7833,1.3417,0.9583,1.025,0.175,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1.0583,0.6833,0.8333,0.5917,1.4917,0.8333,1.4583,1.2583,0.8417,1.025,0.4,0,0.0083,0,0.0333,0.2,0.2833,1.2333,1.2083,0.8417,0.7333,0.7,0.7833,1.2833,1.2667,0.7583,1.125,0.7667,0.625,1.0833,0.675,0.6917,0.4,0.1417,0.375,0.0167,00,0.0583,0.0917,0.2167,0.6083,0.9083,1.35,1.3,1.425,1.6417,0.925,0.875,1.3583,0.7083,0.65,0.8917,1.83,1.575,0.8917,0.5917,0.375,0.0667,0.0333,0.0083,0,0.0083,0.1,0.4083,0.9833,1.1083,1.0667,1.1917,1.375,0.5333,0.975,1.3833,0.725,0.9417,1,1.0083,1.275,0.7833,1.1417,0.5917,0.2917,0.1,0,0,0,0.0333,0.233,0.3667,0.7167,0.6833,1.55,1.175,0.9417,1.025,1.425,1.275,1.0583,1.1583,0.65,0.9417,1.4583,1.3417,1.9083,1.5417,0.75,0.1583,0.0083,0,0,0.1833,0.075,0.4083,0.6667,1.1,0.6167,0.8167,1.2667,1.6333,1.4083,0.9,0.975,0.8,0.7667,1.1417,2.0917,1.1667,0.675,0.65,0.4833,0.525,0.025,0.075,0,0,0.025,0.2333,0.5833,1.0833,0.9917,0.775,0.9667,0.6167)

and the other set is : 
0.0055
0.0008
0.0001
0
0
0
0.0001
0.0009
0.0005
0.0022
0.0001
0
0.0111
0.0004
0.0018
0.0256
0.0016
0.0001
0.0283
0.0345
0.0046
0.0144
0.0732
0.0014
0.0002
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.0004
0.0003
0.0002
0.02
0.0003
0.0004
0.0005
0.0018
0.0031
0.0005
0
0
0
0
0.005
0.0072
0.0003
0.0004
0.0004
0.0033
0.0036
0.0025
0.0269
0.0005
0.0001
0.0002
0.0033
0.0089
0.0002
0.0003
0.0021
0
0
0.0008
0
0
0
0
0
0.0002
0.0003
0.0015
0.0031
0.0002
0
0.0009
0.0176
0.0022
0.0003
0.0156
0.0446
0.0001
0
0.0087
0.0125
0.3403
0.0001
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.0044
0.0003
0.0027
0.0003
0.0051
0.0002
0.0009
0.0014
0.011
0.0012
0.0009
0
0.003
0.001
0.0051
0.0007
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.0001
0.0047
0.0012
0.0007
0.0367
0.0311
0.0004
0.0002
0.0003
0.0997
0.0003
0
0.0099
0.0132
0.0006
0.0057
0.0099
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0.0019
0.0046
0.0001
0.0107
0.002
0.0016
0.0062
0.1011
0.2257
0.0001
0.0002
0.007
0.1401
0.0278
0.0026
0.0055
0.0018
0.0011
0.0002
0.0004
0.0003
0.0003
0.0002
0.0006
0.0017
0.009
0.0078
0.0154
0.0171
0.0021
0.0025
0.0069

And I need to find the best fitting probability distribution with good graphs  and a step by step explanation of what each graph represent , so I can use them for further analysis

The data is the readings of traffic in a mobile network node and the values are measured in Erlang. which is typically a negative exponential distribution fit. but I need to test it anyways.
the second set is the data traffic and they are measured in GB.
therefore you can see that all readings are > 0.

Comment: Your data is discrete with many values recorded as exactly 0. A cursory examination of the distribution shape indicates a much heavier tail (considering the mean, say) than would be consistent with (a binned) exponential.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty clearly an exponential distribution is a poor description of the shape.

Here's a histogram for your first data set:

[image]

Assuming these are conceptually discretized data that are notionally continuous before being discretized (so we could consider an exponential for the underlying variable), the spike at 0 is too high, the it drops much too far, there's a bulge around 1 that we shouldn't see and the tail is too heavy.

The issue with the second data set is quite similar.

Comment: Thank you Glen_b  for your comment. 
would you please provide me with a better fitting distribution, with a good explanation of the steps you used to generate the graph. I will appreciate it if you could guide me to do it since I am new to this
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to fit a distribution? (What would you do with some fitted distribution?) ... The fitted exponential was generated by MLE (which is the same as choosing the exponential distribution with the same mean as the data) then that density was plotted over a histogram of the data.

Comment: I want to know the fitting distribution so I can understand the future behavior of the data. 
This data is traffic measurements for a mobile network for a period of 24 hours. The two sets are two different types of traffic. The first set is expected to be en exponential distribution, because many studies confirmed that this type of traffic is generated -vely exponential during the day hours. The second set is what I need to investigate.but it is also expected to be negatively distributed, though I need to investigate. 
I know so little of statics and even less about r

Comment: Yes, it makes sense that if there was a simple, well understood distribution that fitted well and that would continue to apply in the future that would be helpful in trying to understand the future behavior. Unfortunately its rare to find data that is well approximated by a mathematically simple distribution. Sometimes some modification (zero-inflated distributions, for example) or combination of distributions (e.g. a mixture of several exponentials) may be reasonable. Neither data set is anywhere near exponential -- not remotely close. They're somewhat similar to each other in shape.